$A(z) \in \mathbb{C}[z]^{n \times n}$ - Exploit matrix structure to find analytical eigenvalues for $n>4$
I have a complex polynomial matrix $A(z) \in \mathbb{C}[z]^{n \times n}$. Generally such a matrix does not allow to analytically calculate the eigenvalue polynomials for $n>4$. However, does anyone know of a special matrix structures that I could potentially exploit to obtain an analytical solution?
